# How to get async html attribut

Tags: angularjs

I have a list of items retreived by an async call and the list is shown with the help of `ng-repeat`. Since the div container of that list has a fixed height (400px) I want the scrollbar to be at the bottom. And for doing so I need the `scrollHeight`. But the `scrollHeight` in `postLink` is not the final height but the initial height.

Example

**ppChat.tpl.html**

```
<!-- Height of "chatroom" is "400px" -->
<div class="chatroom">
  <!-- Height of "messages" after all messages have been loaded is "4468px" -->
  <div class="messages" ng-repeat="message in chat.messages">
    <chat-message data="message"></chat-message>
  </div>
</div>
```

**ppChat.js**

```
// [...]
compile: function(element) {
  element.addClass('pp-chat');

  return function(scope, element, attrs, PpChatController) {
    var messagesDiv;
    // My idea was to wait until the messages have been loaded...
    PpChatController.messages.$loaded(function() {
      // ...and then recompile the messages div container
      messagesDiv = $compile(element.children()[0])(scope);
      // Unfortunately this doesn't work. "messagesDiv[0].scrollHeight" still has its initial height of "400px"
    });
  }
}
```

Can someone explain what I missed here?

As required here is a [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/CCzHFUoGSCc0zEWlM3nA?p=preview) of it

Comment: kindly, create a plunkr so that others can edit/improve your code.

Comment: where did you get the 2000px scroll height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the `scrollHeight` of the div after the DOM is updated by doing it in the following way.

The below directive sets up a watch on the array i.e. a collection, and uses the $timeout service to wait for the DOM to be updated and then it scrolls to the bottom of the div.

```
chatDirective.$inject = ['$timeout'];

function chatDirective($timeout) {
  return {
    require: 'chat',
    scope: {
      messages: '='
    },
    templateUrl: 'partials/chat.tpl.html',
    bindToController: true,
    controllerAs: 'chat',
    controller: ChatController,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ChatController) {
      scope.$watchCollection(function () {
        return scope.chat.messages;
      }, function (newValue, oldValue) {
        if (newValue.length) {
          $timeout(function () {
            var chatBox = document.getElementsByClassName('chat')[0];
            console.log(element.children(), chatBox.scrollHeight);
            chatBox.scrollTop = chatBox.scrollHeight;
          });
        }
      });
    }
  };
}
```

The updated plunker is [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/mqWA7HS4pmFjFAuC6QoM?p=preview).

Also in your Controller you have written as,

```
  var Controller = this;

  this.messages = [];
```

It's better to write in this way, here vm stands for ViewModel

```
AppController.$inject = ['$timeout'];

function AppController($timeout) {
  var vm = this;

  vm.messages = [];

  $timeout(
    function() {
      for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        vm.messages.push({
          message: getRandomString(),
          created: new Date()
        });
      }
    },
    3000
  );
}
```